# Return the value of a JS function and use it as the value for an input button

Tags: html, javascript

I want to set a JavaScript function which returns a string, and that string to be used as a value for a button. Something like this:

```
function test(){
 x = "some text";
 return x;
}
```

I want to use this function in a input element in the value attribute. Something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="s1" value="test()" />
```

Unfortunatly the button doesn't show "some text"  but "test()" on the button. How can i fix this?

Comment: here `value` is an attribute, the value of an attribute will be a string and it will not be parsed. AFAIK there is no way to achieve this

Comment: JS aint JSP! Can't do it *that* directly..

Comment: If you need to update html element value and(or) attributes dynamically, look at knockout.js framework

Comment: @ArunPJohny with some JS and by using a data- attribute instead of the using the value attribute directly, it is absolutely possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16168318/171933

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could do:

```
<input type="button" id="s1" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 var elem = document.getElementById("s1");
 elem.value = "some text";
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to set the value of the button would be to use the HTML DOM, or a framework like JQuery. This also has a [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/omedil/1/edit).

For example,

**HTML** - Runs function `test` when document loads.

```
<body onload = "test()">
  <input type="button" id="s1" value="" />
</body>
```

**JavaScript -**

```
function test(){
 x = "some text";
 document.getElementById("s1").value =x;
}
```

[View JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/omedil/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

value attribute for html button accepts only text. see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp).

What I understand from your question is you want a html button whose value should be set by a javascript function. you can achieve this the other way around.

Get button element using `document.getElementById` and set the `value` inside the `test()`

you code should looks like this:

```
<input type="button" id="s1"/>

<script>
   function test(){
      document.getElementById('s1').value ='some text'; //s1 is the id of html button
   };
   test(); //dont forget to call function
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in an elegant way by using custom data attributes.

See a JSFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/NJ5sK/

Basically, you mark your input elements with the name of the function that should be called to return its value. Then you grab all the elements that have the `data-value-function` attribute, run the function and assign the value.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" data-value-function="cheese" />
<input type="text" data-value-function="animal" />
```

**JS:**

```
window.cheese = function() {
    return "Limburger";
}

window.animal = function() {
    return "Cat";
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*[data-value-function]');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var valueFunctionName = elements[i].getAttribute('data-value-function');
    elements[i].value = window[valueFunctionName]();
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(){
    x = "some text";
    document.getElementById('s1').value = x;
}
```

Comment: the `test()` will not get executed

Comment: the function will work , it just has to be triggered.. perhaps an onClick etc. not sure why it was downvoted as he didnt say how he wanted to trigger it.

Comment: It'll "work", but only if the only purpose of this function is to set the button value. What if you had, say, `Math.round( 1.5 )` in place of `test()`?

Comment: the only difference between my answer and the others is that they put a trigger (onload() or a post script) to change the value. I suppose we should downvote all those as well.